# Define array with variable index

Tags: php, arrays

My code:

```
$rank_content = file('https://www.championsofregnum.com/index.php?l=1&ref=gmg&sec=42&world=2');
    $line_count = 0;
//initializing only the first few keys because of no reason (the latter ones aren't in use yet)
$rankNameArr = array(0=>42,1=>42,2=>42,3=>42,4=>42,5=>42,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72);
$rankRlmpArr = array(0=>42,1=>42,2=>42,3=>42,4=>42,5=>42,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72);
while ($line = array_shift($rank_content)) { // retrieving line after line of the website, does work indeed
    $line_count += 1;
    if(strpos($line, "Warrior #") || strpos($line, "Archer #") || strpos($line, "Mage #"))
    {
        $rankNameArr[$line_count] = $line_count + 1; // HERE nothing happens
        $rankRlmpArr[$line_count] = $line_count + 2; // nothing happens here, too
    }
}
```

Why does

```
echo $rankNameArr[2];
echo $rankRlmpArr[2];
```

give me the value `42` instead of the correct value? If I replace `$line_count` with a real number, the script works properly.

My intention is to store the value `$line_count + 1` into `$rankNameArr` at position `$line_count`. Not very complicated actually

EDIT -------------
Forget everything above, please. I finally reduced the script to the actual problem:

```
    $arr = array(0=>42,1=>42,2=>42,3=>42,4=>42,5=>42,6=>42);
$counter=0;
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) {
    $arr[$counter]=$i;
}
echo $arr[5];
```

This sadly echoes 42. I have no idea how to have `$arr[$counter]` store the actual value of `$i`.

Comment: What is in `$rank_content`?  Without understanding this, it is unclear what is happening in your loop. Also, why explicitly define keys for some items in array and not for others? This is very odd. What is this section of code actually intending to do?

Comment: edited the starting post

Comment: Are `Warrior #`, `Archer #` etc. at the beginning of the lines in the file? If so, you will never enter your conditional as those conditions would all evaluate to `0` which is falsey.  You may want to be more specific in your conditials like `if(false !== strpos($line, "Warrior #") || false !== strpos($line, "Archer #") || false !== strpos($line, "Mage #"))`

Comment: no, they aren't. strpos() is only used to check their existance in the specified line. I could have also used preg_match() instead.
"$rankNameArr[$line_count] = $line_count + 1;" gets called 72 times, I assure you, but still nothing happens.

Comment: since the script is working when I replace "$line_count" with a real number like 2 instead, it seems the program cannot find the specific key. But I have no idea why // 
edit. Thanks for the hint. No, those substrings are NOT at the very first position in these lines; I should have told you by now, sorry

Comment: Why array_shift instead of a foreach or for loop?

Comment: I'm testing myself and for some reason "array_shift" doesn't seem to play nicely with "while"...

Comment: hello, please, have a look at the starting post again, I added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea how to have $arr[$counter] store the actual value of $i.

`$counter` is set to `0`, so `$arr[$counter]` is the same as saying `$arr[0]`. If you echo `$arr[0]` you'll see that it *is* being changed while the rest are left alone, which means your code is working.

However if you want `$counter` to increment also, you just need to tell it to do so:

```
$arr = array(0=>42,1=>42,2=>42,3=>42,4=>42,5=>42,6=>42);
$counter=0;
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) {
  $counter++;
  $arr[$counter]=$i;
}
echo $arr[5];
```

Comment: Or `$arr[$i] = $i` ....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep. Or even `$counter = $i;` instead of `$counter++`.

Comment: My point is that `$counter` itself is then entirely redundant.

Comment: okay now. It took me, like, 10 years to realize, but $rankNameArr[$line_count] should have been replaced with a counter on its own;$rankNameArr[2] never got initialized, $line_count stores the amount of lines instead of an actual counter.
Thanks everybody! :)